# Possibly a slang word related to, but not quite synonymous with, "exposed" or "jinxed"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a line in a wonderfully entertaining, though oddly obscure, movie with a star-studded cast and a fast-paced script whose meaning I can't quite catch.

All of the action takes place in New Orleans in the 90's. A motley crew of specialized felons kidnap a billionaire owner of a huge company for ransom. As the crew and the victim sit in an abandoned house discussing their next move (I'm simplifying), they suddenly discover they're on TV: the police know their names; their photos are being shown.

Now they have two (2) choices. One, they can simply walk away and disappear. Two, they can go forward with the original plan. Each member of the crew now describes, to the best of their ability, the pros and cons of either approach from his or her point of view.

[image]

One of the members is German (played by Til Scheiger in what I think is his best role to date). He submits (in a deliberately thick German accent, I think) that there's no original plan anymore, because everything has changed; he says:

"Nothing's the same, man. We're all ... what's that fucking word? ... hinked. We're hinked here."

Or at least that's what it sounded like to me. Now I'm not aware of any meaning of the word "hinked" that could stand in for "jinxed," "exposed," "derailed," or "marked." Maybe his accent has something to do with it, or it might be a New Orleans, or just plain old Southern, lingo of some sort - I don't know.

Any ideas?

Here's the **sound file** with just that line on it:

http://vocaroo.com/i/s07shGnVO77f

Comment: @Rathony: Thank you. Sometimes the keyboard sticks, but my spelling does get awfully impressionistic at times, as if it had a mind of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***hexed***.

> hex
>
> : to affect as if by an evil spell :  jinx [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hex)
>
> : to bring bad luck to; jinx [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hex)

Comment: It would make perfect sense, wouldn't it? But, no, it's not "hex," unfortunately.

Comment: Check out the sound file in the question post.

Comment: @Ricky Sounds like it's "jinxed " mispronounced in a thick German accent as something along the lines of "hinxed/hinked."

Comment: @Ricky What's more, "jinxed" makes a lot of sense for a movie whose action is set in New Orleans. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it sure does. I believe you might be right.